# Unreasonable laptop performance

Tags: performance, hardware-failure, nvidia-geforce, lenovo-laptop

My laptop has some serious issues  with performance. The specifications of my laptop:

Lenovo Y50-70
 RAM: 16GB
 CPU: Intel i7-4710HQ @2.5GHz
 Graphics: GeForce GTX 860M 4GB

First I should mention that I am a responsible user and give attention to the maintenance of my PC. Below I list some of the problems:

- Ctrl+ left arrow, Ctrl+right arrow to mark a text has a delay which varies from zero to 0.5 sec (0.5 sec is such a huge time)
- Ctrl+PageUp, etc. in every browser to change from tab to tab has delay. Furthermore, when the tab goes to the desired I see the previous frame of this tab for about 0.5 sec. I understand that when I have a YouTube video. It's like having the last frame of the previous time I was in this tab.
- Delay when closing a tab.
- Google maps are really really slow. There is a huge delay when moving the map.
- I have noticed that videos that pop-up (for example, trailers from IMDB) are lagging too much. Another example, when I watch videos in Udemy, an online platform for courses with videos, the video and the sound are not synchronized (I have tested it in other laptops and there wasn't this audio unsynchronized with video).
- When making a window bigger there is delay to display the whole image of the tab in a browser. Example:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Additional notes:

- I also have to mention that when I made a format it seems that the problem was gone, but a week later the same problems reoccurred. (I repeatedly formatted 3 times with the same results).
- I do not download or visit any kind of suspicious files/websites.
- In Device Manager all the devices' status are 'this device is working properly'.(I don't trust it, but I had to mention it also).
  A screanshot of the taskmanager jobs and activity:
  [image]

Everything seems ok here...

The specifications of the laptop indicate that this is a really good laptop, but there are times that I use my old laptop (Core i5 with 4GB RAM). Do you have any advice about in what direction to move to troubleshoot the bad functionality of my laptop? Is it a software problem or a hardware problem?

**Note:** Both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 have this problem.

Comment: Did this start around the time you upgraded to Windows 10?

Comment: No. Both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 had that problem.

Comment: Have you freshly installed Windows since the problem started?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your last question. I have formatted my laptop couples of times. The problem disappears but appears a period after.

Comment: Have you tried installing either win8 or 10, and letting windows find the best device drivers for each component in device manager, rather than using lenovo's own drivers? I know their power management software and 'lenovo support centre' are both very bad pieces of software. Only install lenovo recommended drivers when windows cannot find an alternative.

Comment: Most of your problems sound browser related, but you've not told us what browser you use or what extensions you install. Additionally do you have any antivirus or other software installed?

Comment: I think that the drivers are found by windows(not sure for that. How can I check that?). As for the last question: it happens in chrome, firefox and explorer. But not only in browser. For example when I am coding in an editor there is delay in changing tab and highlighting text etc.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris you said the problem disappears after you format, then shows up later... This sounds like you are adding something that is causing the lagging, because it doesn't occur immediately after reformatting.

Comment: I format the laptop and I add specific softwares from the first day(Matlab,python,R,spotify, etc) and after I do not add anything else.1-2 weeks later I can understand a difference in the performance. I don't believe any of the softwares that I add is causing it.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris If you open Task Manager > Performance tab, are any graphs flatlined at 100%?

Comment: @Mooseman I have updated my answer(just a further comment. This is not an day problem. I have followed the typical procedure of checking some simple 'things' to see if everythig is ok)

Answer (score 3):

i've seen this on lenovos.  try upgrading the bios as a starter. If you have an SSD, make sure the bios is set to SSD to reflect it, and upgrade firmware for SSD

Comment: There is an 8GB ssd disk. Can you be more explicit by what you mean 'ugrading the bios as a starter'?  And how to set my bios in SSD?

Comment: check here and download the bios update util:  http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Lenovo-Y-Series-laptops/Y50-70-Notebook-Lenovo?linkTrack=Homepage:Body_Search%20Products.  Look in the bios for a setting called "Storage" or something similar and set the mode to SSD.  IF you can't find it, then it could be that your bios is locked by lenovo, so don't worry about it, otherwise, you can unlock your bios - see this thread https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-unlock-advanced-menu-lenovo-y50-70  which will unlock all your menus etc and give you a performance hit  .

Comment: you also need to track down a firmware update utility for your SSD.  They can reduce laptops to snail pace.  Make sure your SSD is fully up to date.  Pingers.

Comment: The 8GB is a cache.  What Pingers is suggesting is replacing the main system drive with a SSD

Comment: an update: Changed the hybrid hard drive to SSD. same problems after a week of usage.. :/